# Compiling Julia system image in a Docker

Tags: python, compilation, julia

I am creating a Docker with Python calling Julia code

I want to compile a Julia system image with my code so that it starts quickly.  This all works fine on my OSX Mac Pro.

In my Dockerfile, I start with Julia and then install Python and my requirements

```
FROM julia:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3 python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
```

Then I install PyJulia and try to compile my code as a system image

```
RUN python3 -m pip install julia
RUN python3 -c "import julia; julia.install()"
RUN python3 -m julia.sysimage --script=/app/v3/src/precompile.jl /app/v3.so
```

Which fails like this

```
RuntimeError: ``julia-py`` executable is not found for Python installed at /usr/bin/python3
The command '/bin/sh -c python3 -m julia.sysimage --script=/app/v3/src/precompile.jl /app/v3.so' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why is julia-py not installed?  Am I missing a step?

Comment: This might be a bug.  Julia-py is installed, but not the same location as python3.  Julia-py is in /usr/local/bin, whereas python3 is in /usr/bin.  When julia-py is executed it produces the message "RuntimeError: ``julia-py`` executable is not found for Python installed at /usr/bin/python3"

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is a bug.  A workaround hack is to copy all the PyJulia stuff to /usr/bin

```
RUN python3 -m pip install julia
RUN python3 -c "import julia; julia.install()"
RUN cp -r /usr/local/bin/* /usr/bin
RUN python3 -m julia.sysimage --script=/app/v3/src/precompile.jl /app/v3.so
```